# Unity How to Control 3D Snake Model Movements and Body Collision (Bend the Model part that collided)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

let's say that i have a Blender Snake Model , what is the best practice to move it and bend it while collided like a real snake body. i tried to divide it but using the `InvokeRepeating()` gave it the old school snake game movement plus a bad harmony between the inputs(update) and the `InvokeRepeating()`, also i did the part follow the previous part method but it's have some glitches while rotating and distances problems. so is there any other good practice ??
this is an image from google of how a snake (model) looks like XD and how the movement looks like [ex of a bended snake Model from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYP8d.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a demonstration of what kind of achievement you want to create? A video would be great. Showing what code you already used would be helpful in understanding what you have tried as well.

Comment: thanks for ur reply , i added a snak image to the topic if that may help , as i said before imagine that you have the model in the topic image how you can get a real snake movements + collisions (ex body bend when head roate about an object tree per ex) do u have a special method ?(unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible solutions

---

**Solution 1**

Use rope-like physics and experiment with which parts of the snake must invoke movement and which parts must only be moved by the other parts. As well as how much each part should move.

In this situation you may benefit from making weight points in the snakes body parts, to make it seem more realistically moving.

---

**Solution 2**

Another way to somewhat achieve it would be to make the classes SnakeHead, SnakeBody and SnakeTail.

When Snakehead then moves, he afterwards tells the nearest body part to move, which tells the next body part to move and so on till you reach the tail.

That way you can have them move closer to where the body part in front of them was a moment ago.

---

**Solution 3**

Follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz8Ga9er3_8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: thanks for ur effort , i tried the solution 2 that i think it looks like the one in 3 but i didnt got the perfect movement i need , i think i will watch the tuto u gave me and try to change something

Comment: I didn't have a complete solution for it, but I believe my suggestions might bring you further towards one. Can also try find other snake tutorials :P, good luck.

Comment: thanks man , that took from me a long time trying to  create a seamless move , and sure ur suggestions are useful , (i want to give u +1 but i think i need some "reputation")

Comment: Yes you need 15 reputation for it.

Comment: yeah i know that